# How can I see global locks in mysql (innodb)?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

If in understand correctly, running `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` acquires a global read lock.

Is there any command I can run in the mysql client which shows me that lock is currently acquired?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/processlist-table.html

Comment: I've tried `show full processlist`. It can show that an "update" query is waiting for the lock to be released, but it doesn't show who holds the lock.

Comment: It does, `the FIRST command before all the write (insert,update,delete) is the owner of the lock`

Comment: Sorry, the lock is not included into processlist;

Comment: @rkosegi that thread is talking about table locks. My question was about a global lock.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

It will show owner of locks and waiters (and lot of other stuff related to innodb)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-monitors.html

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks/

Comment: I'm familiar with the command, but it doesn't show global locks acquired by `flush tables with read lock` unless I missed it.

Comment: You need at least one of the PROCESS privileges for this operation. Any way I can do this without any PROCESS privileges?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a global lock.once you come out of session ,it releases it

Comment: Given that the edit queue is full and not clearing... "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK" is a global lock, but it is also tied to the current login session only. To clear the READ LOCK, exit the session. There is not a command to run that clears it.
Then log back in to a new SQL session and run

    SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

and you will see that closing the previous session releases the lock, as all transactions will no longer be waiting.